# I'm having problems with View and Adapter View. Below is my code which Im working on

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, onclicklistener

Android studio gives me the opportunity to import View when I hover over View view, however the code goes all red, as View is incompatible with AdapterView. I'm not sure whether there is another import that I should use. I also have errors with newsItems.setAdapter and newsItems.setOnClickListener. Cannot resolve method setOnClickListener and public void on itemClick, error is Expression expected, method expected.

```
 ArrayAdapter<NewsItem> adapter = new customAdapter();

        ListView newsItems = (ListView) (findViewById(newsItems));
        newsItems.setAdapter(adapter);

        newsItems.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick (AdapterView <?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivityNews.this, "MyListView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        });

    }
```

Comment: View is incompatible with AdapterView?

Comment: `findViewById(newsItems)` should be `findViewById(R.id.newsItems)`. Not the solution to your question, but will throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `onItemClickListener` like below:

```
newsItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                // Do what needs to be done when an item is clicked here

        }
    });
```